# How to compare two event results? (Maybe by using local or global variables?)

Tags: javascript

I am actually trying to change the color of a `div` on click. I have sixteen `div`s. On click, a Javascript function is called which switch cases for each box. While changing the color, I call another function where I match the previous color and the current color. I have made the `Color` variable as global, and it changes for each click for each box. I don't know how to compare it.

Following is my code.

```
    Color = "#FFF"; 
    Score = 0;        
    function showCard(mynum)
    {
        switch(mynum)
        {
        case 1:
            Color="#000000";
            break;
        case 2:
            Color="#FF0000";
            break;
        case 3:
            Color="#000000";
            break;
        case 4:
            Color="#FF0000";
            break;
        default:

        }

        document.getElementById(mynum).style.backgroundColor=Color;
        getScore(Color);
    }

    function getScore(clr){

        if(Color==clr)  
            Score++;
        else
            Score--;

        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML= Score;


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the previous color before updating it.

```
function showCard(mynum)
{
    var oldColor = Color;
    switch(mynum)
    {
    case 1:
        Color="#000000";
        break;
    case 2:
        Color="#FF0000";
        break;
    case 3:
        Color="#000000";
        break;
    case 4:
        Color="#FF0000";
        break;
    default:

    }

    document.getElementById(mynum).style.backgroundColor=Color;
    getScore(oldColor);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar for your solution. I also want to control these divs through keyboard navigation keys? could you please guide me how to do that. I mean i want to change the color by entering and switching to divs through navigation keys? any suggestion?

Comment: Not totally sure, I guess it involves binding the `keyup` event on `body`, and then checking the `keyCode` to see which navigation key it is.